# How Should I compute signatures in API?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create API for yobit. For now, I will do something very simple, namely get info.

In Python, the code sort of looks like this

```
 url = 'https://yobit.net/tapi'
    values['method'] = method
    values['nonce'] = str(int(time.time()))
    body = urlencode(values)
    signature = hmac.new(self.secret, body, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Key': self.key,
        'Sign': signature
    }
```

I basically want to replace code  `hmac.new(self.secret, body, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()` with vb.net equivalent.

This my current code

```
Public Overrides Sub readbalances()
    Dim secret = _secret
    Dim url = "https://yobit.net/tapi"
    Dim key = New Tuple(Of String, String)("Key", _apiKey)
    Dim parameters = "method=getInfo&nonce=" + Str(Int(DateTime.Now))
    Dim sig = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512().ToString 'What should I put here?
    Dim sigtupple = New Tuple(Of String, String)("Sign", sig)
    Dim result = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1("url", {key, sigtupple}, parameters)
End Sub
```

What should I do?

Content of downloadString1 is the following but let's just say it performs as expected

```
Public Shared Function downloadString1(url As String, headers As Tuple(Of String, String)(), postdata As String) As String
    Dim wc = New CookieAwareWebClient

    For Each header In headers
        wc.Headers.Add(header.Item1, header.Item2)
    Next
    Dim result = wc.UploadString(url, postdata)
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: I'll add bounty in 2 days. I need the answer fast.

Comment: You'll need to convert the string body into a byte stream of a specific encoding (Python hides this detail from you) and then pass that into `HMACSHA512`.

Comment: I think so. How exactly should I do so?